# Datadir in R - How to load an RDS file

Tags: r

I've recently switched to a macbook and started working with R and was wondering how it was possible to load a file from my own harddisk into r.

Currently i set the working directly correctly however when using:

```
dataDir <- "..."

dat1 <- readRDS(paste0(dataDir, "satify.rds"))
```

my file is in:
`"~/Documents/r studio directory/Assignment 2/data"`
However i am unable to get the file to load.

error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
   cannot open compressed file
```

Comment: Suggestion:    Type out what you are getting from `paste0(dataDir, "satify.rds")`

Comment: Yep, it's a better practice to use `paste0(dataDir, "/satify.rds")` to always separate the file name from the directory name.

Comment: Set the working directory: `setwd("~/Documents/r studio directory/Assignment 2/data")`. Then read: `dat1 <- readRDS("satify.rds")`

Comment: Use `file.path` to concatenate path elements; it will use the operating system's correct directory deliminator.

Comment: > dat1 <- readRDS("/satify.rds")
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file '/satify.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: This is the error i get after i try it with "/satify.rds" and without the /. I've set the working directory propperly, the file is in there. To be honest, when loading in files i've never had this issue before

Comment: I've found the correct file path using the terminal in macbook and dragging it in. -- "/Users/anwar/Documents/r\ studio\ directory/Assignment\ 2/data/" -- . However after setting the working directory to this file path and then dat1 <- readRDS("satify.rds") it still gives the same error. Is there something i'm overseeing?

Answer (score 1):

To be fair i'm not exactly sure why it's working now. However i just completely removed the dataDir line and just used:

```
    rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
    setwd("~/Documents/r studio directory/Assignment 2/data")
    dat1 <- readRDS("/Users/anwar/Documents/r\ studio\
    directory/Assignment\ 2/data/satisfy.rds")
```

(The dat1 and directory line are one line of code)
And got the link to the file using the terminal on mac OS and it's now working properly.

Thanks for the help everyone!